# error on sending sms by ozeki message server by php?

Tags: php, mysql, sms

I want to make a online auction house like ebay. In my website, After complete bidding of any product, a sms will be send to both buyer (bidder) and seller. All code works well, But in the following page, I have some error that can't be solved. I include this page every of my page. When I open any of my page then some error is showed. The error is ::

```
  Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in    D:\xampp\htdocs\auction\reload.php on line 13

  Fatal error: Cannot redeclare sendSMS2() (previously declared in D:\xampp\htdocs\auction\reload.php:61) in D:\xampp\htdocs\auction\reload.php on line 68
```

I also use some code for sending sms some page such as user registration, buyer (bidder) notification etc. All of other code does well, But the following page makes me trouble.  My code is ::

Reload.php

```
<?php      
   mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());  
   mysql_select_db("auction2") or die(mysql_error()); // select database

  $now = strtotime("now");      // get prisent time
  $today = date("Y-m-d",$now);      

 //after certain time [ given( expire_date ) < Today ] product will be deleted by updating value 'status' = '1'
   $load = mysql_query(" UPDATE product SET status='1' WHERE product_id='$product_id' AND exp_date < '$today' ") or die(mysql_error()); 

if( mysql_num_rows($load) > 0)          // if any product found  
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($load) ) {         //fetch result
       mysql_select_db("auction2") or die(mysql_error());      // select database

       $product_id = $row['product_id'];        // select product Id

        // finding the maximum ( money ), product_id, seller_name, buyer_name   
        $max = mysql_query("SELECT product_id, seller_name, buyer_name,  MAX(money) FROM product_bet
                            WHERE product_id='$product_id' ") or die(mysql_error());

        $row2 = mysql_fetch_array($max) or die(mysql_error());  //fetch_result

        $product_id = $row[0];  //product_id
        $seller_name = $row[1];  //sellerName
        $buyer_name = $row[2];   //buyer_Name
        $money = $row[3];       //maximum money

        //finding the product name
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT product_name FROM product WHERE product_id='$product_id' ") or die(mysql_error());
        $pro = mysql_fetch_array($query) or die(mysql_error());  //fetch result

        $productName = $pro['product_name'];  //product name

        //finding seller cell phone number
        $query2 = mysql_query("SELECT seller_phone FROM seller_info WHERE seller_name='$seller_name' ") or die(mysql_error()); 
        $SP = mysql_fetch_arry($query2 ) or die(mysql_error());
        $sellerPhone = $SP['seller_phone'];  //seller cell phone number


        // finding buyer cell phone number  
        $query3 = mysql_query("SELECT buyer_phone FROM buyer_info WHERE buyer_name='$buyer_name' ") or die(mysql_error()); 
        $SP2 = mysql_fetch_arry($query2 ) or die(mysql_error());
        $buyerPhone = $SP2['buyer_phone'];  //buyer cell phone number

        $msg = "Mr. $seller_name, your product ( $productName ) is selled at taka $money to".
          "Mr. $buyer_name. His contact number is $buyerPhone ";    // message will be shown on cell phone


        $msg2 = "Mr. $buyer_name, you win to buy $productName at taka $money".
        "you can contact with Mr. $buyer_name, His contact number is $buyerPhone ";

        sendSMS2( $sellerPhone, $msg );  //function call for sending message to seller
        sendSMS2( $buyerPhone, $msg2 );  // function call for sending message to buyer

    }           



        function sendSMS2( $phoneNumber, $msg) {    // send sms 
    $sql = mysql_select_db("ozekisms") or die(mysql_error());

    $sqlX = "INSERT INTO ozekimessageout ( receiver, msg, status )".
                        "VALUES ('$phoneNumber', '$msg', 'send')";
    $check = mysql_query($sqlX) or die(mysql_error());
    //mysql_close("ozekisms", $sql);
}
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

$load = mysql_query(" UPDATE product SET status='1' WHERE product_id='$product_id' AND exp_date < '$today' ") or die(mysql_error());

An UPDATE query does not return rows. The query is good, but you cannot do

if( mysql_num_rows($load) > 0)

try mysql_rows_affected or something like that